# How to use re to search for negative number?

Tags: python

I have a script that opens up grabs an integer from the user and saves it as `results[1]`.

It then opens up myfile.config and searches for an integer after a string.  The string is `locationID=`.
So the string with the number should look like:

```
locationID="34"
```

or whatever random number is there.
It replaces the current number with the number from results.

So far, my script checks if there is a number and if there is no number listed after `locationID=`.

How can I make it check and replace a negative number?

Here is the original:

```
def replaceid:

    source = "myfile.config"
    newtext = str(results[1])
    with fileinput.FileInput(source, inplace=True, backup='.bak') as file:
        for line in file:
            pattern = r'(?<=locationId=")\d+'  # find 1 or more digits that come
                                              # after the string locationid     

            if re.search(pattern, line):
                sys.stdout.write(re.sub(pattern, newtext, line)) # adds number after locationid
                fileinput.close()
            else:
                sys.stdout.write(re.sub(r'(locationId=)"', r'\1"' + newtext, line)) # use sys.stdout.write instead of "print"
                # using re module to format                                                              
                # adds a location id number after locationid even if there was no number originally there        
                fileinput.close()
```

This is not working for me:

```
def replaceid:

    source = "myfile.config"
    newtext = str(results[1])
    with fileinput.FileInput(source, inplace=True, backup='.bak') as file:
        for line in file:
            pattern = r'(?<=locationId=")\d+'  # find 1 or more digits that come
                                              # after the string locationid     
            patternneg = r'(?<=locationId=-")\d+'

            if re.search(pattern, line):
                sys.stdout.write(re.sub(pattern, newtext, line)) # adds number after locationid
                fileinput.close()

            elif re.search(patternneg, line): # if Location ID has a negative number
                sys.stdout.write(re.sub(patternneg, newtext, line)) # adds number after locationid
                fileinput.close()   

            else:
                sys.stdout.write(re.sub(r'(locationId=)"', r'\1"' + newtext, line)) # use sys.stdout.write instead of "print"
                # using re module to format                                                              
                # adds a location id number after locationid even if there was no number originally there        
                fileinput.close()
```

Comment: Have you tried something like re.sub("locationId=([-\d]+)", newtext, line)?

Comment: locationId=\"(-?\d+)\" matches both locationId="34" and locationId="-34" and has the number as group. You can verify it here: https://regex101.com/r/r3bRW6/2

Comment: How to I enter that into my pattern variable?  This just completely erases the locationid string from my document:   pattern = 'locationId=\"(-?\d+)\"'

Answer (score 1):

Since you are not using the matched digit (whether positive or negative) you could  change the pattern to match anything between double quotes `.([^"]+)` even if it's not a digit

```
pattern = r'(?<=locationId=").([^"]+)'
```

To cover the case of an empty `""` you could change the pattern to `.([^"]*)`.  Also,you might want to extend the pattern for the cases when there are empty spaces before/after `locationId` something like `r'(?<=locationId")\s*=\s*.([^"]*)'`.

Comment: Problem I have with this is that it messes up my 'else' statment where it # adds a location id number after locationid even if there was no number originally there